# A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter

Tags: c#, .net, struct, pass-by-reference

Hello I'm having trouble figuring this out. I have these structs and classes.

```
struct Circle
{ ... }

class Painting
{
     List<Circle> circles;

     public List<Circle> circles
     {
          get { return circles; }
     }
}
```

I am trying to modify one of the circles inside the painting class from outside it, using this code:

```
MutatePosition(ref painting.Circles[mutationIndex], painting.Width, painting.Height);
```

This line is giving me a compiler error:

> A property, indexer or dynamic member
>   access may not be passed as an out or
>   ref parameter

Why is this, and what can I do to solve it without changing my code too much?

Comment: BTW - I like your alias (CantMutate), even if it is obviously a one-off for this question ;)

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll keep it for whenever I post on here :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The error is pretty clear - you can't pass a property to a ref parameter of a method.

You need to make a temporary:

```
var circle = painting.Circles[mutationIndex];
MutatePosition(ref circle, painting.Width, painting.Height);
painting.Circles[mutationIndex] = circle;
```

That being said, mutable structs are often a bad idea.  You might want to consider making this a class instead of a struct.

Comment: Just a question, why does accessing the struct like I was doing count as accessing a property? I could understand if I was accessing the list itself.

Comment: @CantMutate: You *are* accessing the property: `ref painting.Circles[mutationIndex]`. That's using an indexer (which is a kind of property) after fetching the list via a property.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thanks, perhaps it's time to go back to the C# book!

Comment: +1, But this doesn't have much to do with mutable structs. Look at the corrected sample you've posted; there's no requirement that `Circle` be a mutable type for it to work. `MutatePosition` could replace the storage location for `circle` entirely with a new `Circle`, and the changes would filter through.

Comment: @Ani: Of course - I was suggesting that mutable structs are a bad idea - separate from this problem.  It was a more of "this might be better off as a class" comment.

Comment: Ok. I still don't understand the "this might be better off as a class" idea, unless of course there's some suggestion which I've missed that the struct in question is mutable .

Comment: @Ani: The struct's obviously mutable - otherwise, there'd be no reason to pass it by ref ;)  The "mutationIndex" is a good hint, too...

Comment: This answer is not useful.Even if you didn't tell this, We would have tried it only.

Answer (score 2):

If there's only one ref param and no return type for MutatePosition you can return the value.

```
painting.Circles[mutationIndex] = MutatePosition(circle, painting.Width, painting.Height);
```

If there are multiple ref params and/or already a return type you can create a new type that includes everything that needs to be returned.

```
class MutateResults() { Circle Circle; object OtherReffedStuff; }
```